# Closing QGIS custom form programmatically?

Tags: python, qgis-2

I have a custom form for entering and editing attribute values of a point shapefile. I also added a button for deleting the actual feature. Deletion of the feature works fine and then I want to close the form.

I tried:

```
MyDialog.close()
```

but it only empties the dialog (all widgets gone) but leaves an empty window.

**How can I close the custom form programmatically?**

System is Windows 8.1, QGSI 2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved it by calling the parent's `accept()` like so:

```
myDialog.parent().accept()
```